How do I get rid of this whitespace in my neocities site?
I'm a beginner at html and css and been working on an old web style neocities site, however there's white spaces on the right and bottom. How do I fix this?
image of the webpage
Webpage with white margins
Css code of the site
body {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
.background-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('e583a4454c3975298b45bd3e2b29b5bd.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.centered-image {
  width: 1000px;
 /* Adjust width as needed */
  height: 900px;
 /* Adjust height as needed */
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/736x/84/e2/72/84e272c50b6d3feb5436043668cd9e70.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
h1 {
  color: #ff4a95;
  font-family: "Paytone One", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(6, 66, 68);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #ff4a95;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90%;
 left: 31%;
}
#Fruits{
 width:40%;
  position:absolute ;
 top: 9%;
 left: 26% ;
}
p {
 font-family: "Gaegu", serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(255, 239, 21);
  position: absolute;
 top: 10%;
 left: 24%;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color:#ff4a95;
  padding-top:2%;
}
#Dancing-anime-angel {
 width: 200px;
  max-width: none;
  position: absolute;
 left: 65%;
 top: 5%;
}
ul {
 font-family: "Gaegu", serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
.box {
  font-family:"Gaegu", serif ;
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: left;
  color: rgb(255, 239, 21);
  width: 200px;
  height: 700px;
  border: 5px solid #ff3f8f;
  background-color: rgb(119, 223, 255);
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius:15px;
}
h2 {
 margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.box2 {
 width: 400px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: rgb(119, 223, 255);
  color: rgb(255, 239, 21);
  position: absolute;
  left:1500px;
  top: 220px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border:5px solid #ff3f8f 
}
h3 {
  font-family:"Gaegu", serif ;
 font-size: xx-large ;
 font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 90%;
 left: 44%
}
div.box2 {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 80%;
}
#lisafrankstamp {
 position:absolute;
  top: 120%;
 left: 2%;
}
#lisafrankgif {
 width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
 left: 100%;
 top: 0%;
}
#Rats-badge {
 position: absolute;
 top: 120%;
 left: 12%;
}
#autism {
 position: absolute;
 top: 120%;
 left: 7%;
}
#Rainbow-window {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 88%;
 left: 20%;
}
#HelloKittyHeader {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 75%;
 left: 3%;
}
#rainbow-field {
 position: absolute;
 top: 843px;
 left: 65px;
}
#Monkee {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 92%;
 left: 56%;
}
#Usahana-plush {
 position: absolute;
 left: 500px;
 bottom: 830px;
}
#Spongebob-blinkie {
 position: absolute;
 top: 118%;
 left: 2%;
}
/* Start https://www.cursors-4u.com */
* {
 cursor: url(https://cur.cursors-4u.net/food/foo-2/foo200.cur), auto !important;
}
/* End https://www.cursors-4u.com */

I tried to mess with margins and padding but nothing has worked yet, I tried messing with the margins and padding and everything else the internet suggested I'm rippping my hair out, how do I fix this??
